# Internacionalización en PyQt5 no funciona

Tags: pyqt5, internacionalización

Estoy probando la internacionalización en PyQt5 pero hasta ahora no cambia de idioma. Este es mi main.py:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
    label = QLabel(self.tr('Apple'))
    self.setCentralWidget(label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    translator = QTranslator()
    if translator.load('translate/es_ES.qm'):
        print('True')
        app.installTranslator(translator)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Para generar el fichero ts utilizo el comando `pylupdate5 main.py -ts translate/es_ES.ts`. Este es el fichero generado (translate/es_ES.ts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="es_ES" sourcelanguage="en">
<context>
    <name>Window</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../probando.py" line="10"/>
        <source>Apple</source>
        <translation>Manzana</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

y después para compilarlo utilizo el comando `lrelease translate/es_ES.ts` que me crea el fichero `translate/es_ES.qm`. Pero el problema es que me sigue apareciento la palabra "Apple" cuando debería aparecerme la palabra "Manzana", compruebo si me está leyendo el fichero y si entra al `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Internacionalización en PyQt5 funciona

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        label = QLabel(self.tr('Apple'))
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #w = Window()                                       # ---
    translator = QTranslator()
    #if translator.load('translate/es_ES.qm'):          # ---
    if translator.load('translate/es_ES'):              # +++
        print('True')
        app.installTranslator(translator)

    w = Window()                                        # +++  
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]